# Hall effect sensor output type - open collector vs RC

Tags: hall-effect, passive-networks

I am about to select a hall effect sensor. Two types are available: one has an open collector (OC) output, the other an RC output. The [datasheet](http://www.hallsensors.de/CYGTS211-212.pdf) states that both are current sinking. But because I neither know what the RC output is (at least I am not sure) nor how it works, I am not able to select one.

My question is about the RC output. Does RC stand for resistor / capacitor to create the output signal? If so, how does it work? My guess would be, that the resistance or capacitance are modified to create a varying output signal.

Because I have to choose between the OC / RC output type I would like to know the advantages of the RC output type. The datasheet only mentions:

> If there is stronger electromagetic interference or the distance between sensor and the measuring 
>   instrument is farther,  an OC output (open collector) is suggested to use.

Why should I choose the RC output type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the OC version,

It appears that "RC" simply means that it is the same as the open collector version BUT there is an internal pullup (NPN) or pulldown (PNP) resistor included inside the package.

[The CYGTS101RC sensor](http://www.hallsensors.de/CYGTS101RC.pdf) also made by Chen Yang has RC output BUT has the decency to say in its data sheet:

- Digital RC output, a pull up resistor is built 
  in the sensor according to customer’s application.

and

- This sensor has a RC (NPN or PNP) output voltage.  A pull-up resistor is built in the sensor. In  order to optimize the value of the pull up resistor in advance one should firstly use the sensor CYGTS101DC or CYGTS101PC for test. After optimized the pull up resistor you can use the sensor CYGTS101RC for your application.

And they are even kind enough to provide this diagram:

[image]